# PHP: Is there an easier reference for docroot than $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?

Tags: php

HTML references the site's "doc root" (like say localhost/) with the slash (`/`) in an attribute like `href="/"` (which by default would go to localhost/index.html or index.php), but I'm not seeing an easy way to specify in PHP the "docroot" like what $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] does...

I've read that if I start a path with `/` (like `'/some.log'`) that slash will refer to the docroot, but I'm finding that's not the case as I've gotten file write permission errors and realpath() says it's trying to write literally to the Linux root folder of /.

Is there some easy way to refer to this? I could define my own constant but the base file (or a universally-included file) is not necessarily a constant in our archaic code base...

Comment: Can you give us examples of code with path that tried to access the path in your server instead of the url?

Comment: I like to utilize `__DIR__` based on the script itself. I think this question is more opinion and personal preference though.

Comment: What is the problem with just using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`? That's what it's there for.

Comment: this sounds to me like something may be up with your servers configuration.

Comment: I stopped relying on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` because between platforms, one would always be empty, the other was never the correct path, and a third just liked to use `.` ... so, meh, whatever if they have fixed this in PHP or server config or not, I find it unreliable.

Comment: Using `/` to find the root directory is pretty well-established, like using `../` to go back a dir, `./` for current dir, etc..

Comment: Not sure my question is being understood here... in HTML `/` is recognized as "relative to the site's doc root"... in PHP, `/` means "the server file system root" (literally `/` in Linux). If I put `file_put_contents('/some.log', "whatever")`, the file will be not be created in doc root but in the OS file system root. I simply am looking for something simpler than specifying $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] each time because it's a lot of typing or searching/copying/pasting.

Comment: Not sure why the question got downvoted when it got some good answers and comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I could find is assigning `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to a constant:

`define('DOCROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);`

It's easier to type and just as global, even in class definitions and instantiated objects, simply called like:

`$path = DOCROOT . '/logfolder';`

This will work as long as the calling script or an included file has the definition.

It is also possible to set server environment variables that are passed down to PHP in a $_ENV array (would is still easier to type), though that is dependent on your server and configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Many `$_SERVER` values are populated with external variables and `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is one of them. It isn't even a standard [CGI](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3875.html) variable either. If you run PHP on top of Apache you'll have such variable with whatever value was set in Apache's [`DocumentRoot` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#documentroot).

Now, you're probably assuming that there's always a one-to-one mapping between file system paths and URL paths. That's not always the case; in fact URL rewriting and router-based applications are kind of nowadays norm.

If you add up the fact that there're also may ways to configure virtual hosts and PHP within Apache... The thing is that `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`:

- Does not necessarily exist
- Is not necessarily correct
- May not be helpful at all

So you have a number of alternatives depending on your use case:

- Define your own value (I'd suggest a PHP constant) as part of your apps boostrapping
- Hard-code a leading path `/`
- … or even use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` as-is ;-)

Comment: Let me explain better... I'm working with like a dozen different folders in /var/www/html... each one of them has their own $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] defined... I simply want a simpler reference in any of those folder's .php files to reference $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] without having to type or copy all that... in HTML it's just `/`, in PHP `/` points to the OS root, not the docroot of the running .php script (which would be in one of a dozen different folders with their own docroot). I would define a constant but the files don't necessarily run the same includes.

Comment: @DaveSky Perhaps you're confusing file system paths (`C:\Windows\notepad.exe`) with URL paths (`http://example.com/fruits/apples`) and reading files from disk with retrieving data from a network connection. But, honestly, I don't know what you mean, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is working via the web server.  The web server has a configuration of... the `DocumentRoot` (apache, not sure what nginx calls it), so the HTML `/` reference will be taken to the correct place BY APACHE.

PHP isn't limited to web programming - I cheerfully admit to using it for database work and processing text files and combinations thereof for utility programming to make my job easier.  Even when used for web programming, it isn't limited to only staying within the webserver-config-defined `DocumentRoot`.  So when you reference `/` you really are referencing the top of the actual file system.

So... nothing is broken, nothing needs changing, but I think the issue is how you are interpreting `/` vs `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and the fact that very similar terminology is used.

Comment: `/` doesn't work with certain things like file_exists; if I run `die("file exists: " . (file_exists('/index.html') ? 'true' : 'false'));`, it shows false. If I run `die("file exists: " . (file_exists({$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']} . 'index.html') ? 'true' : 'false'));`, it returns true. So our server at least is not treating `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and `/` the same way in PHP. I simply wanted an easier way of specifying `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` without having to type all that. I think the easiest way must be something like `define('DOCROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` somewhere.

Comment: Also specifying the path without the slash will just consider the path to be in the same directory as the file initially ran (like index.php), so omitting the slash would be contextual whereas `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not contextual.